# How to understand negative pixels in CNNs and the ReLU

Tags: tensorflow

I'm new to computer vision.

Does the negative pixels produced by the convolutional layer filters mean it's black in color?

And if the ReLU only converts all negative pixels to 0, is it just converting black color to black color?

Answer (score -1):

0 or negative does not necessarily mean black color. For example, if you rescale pixel values of an image between 0-1, that does not mean all the pixels will look like black color. It is relative i.e. now pixels closer to the value 1 will look like closer to white color. Similar situation happens in your case.